# Refresh doesn't seems to work for my BootstrapVue <b-table> component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Despite I'am using refresh method, my  doesn't get updated after I change some element of its *items[]* records:

I have to add a dummy/ghost record and then delete it to get the record I want updated:

```
        this.items[this.posItemEdited] = element;
        //this.$refs['theTable'].refresh(); //Doesn't work
        //this.$root.$emit('bv::refresh::table', 'theTable'); //Doesn't work

        //TRICK: add and delete 
        this.items.push(element);
        this.items.splice(this.items.length - 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code does not work because of caveats in a reactivity of Vue.js

```
this.items[this.posItemEdited] = element;
```

See [Reactivity for arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

To solve this problem you need to use `$set`:

```
this.$set(this.items, this.posItemEdited, element)
```